# Formula for converting a RBG image to a black and white image

Tags: image

I'm working on a project where you start with a RBG image and have to convert it to a black and white image. I made it a grey scale image but now I don't know how to make it black and white. Is there a formula to do this? For example: with grey scale you add all 3 pixels then divided them by 3 to get the average.

Comment: you can't get the result you are looking for unless you use dithering

Comment: In python there was a file written with pygame that will display an image and have options to change the pixels and everything, I've used it already to make different images

Comment: check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither

Comment: ok that actually helped a lot, thank you :)